# Where can I find high-quality artwork for my app?

Tags: iphone, icons, artwork

I am looking especially for tab bar icons, buttons and backgrounds. Are there any websites intended for this purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there free iPhone navigation bar icon sets available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813096/are-there-free-iphone-navigation-bar-icon-sets-available)

Comment: See also [Good sites for getting graphics for iPhone Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509844/good-sites-for-getting-graphics-for-iphone-apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Glyphish](http://glyphish.com/) have great icons I use in lots of apps. Their pro series are well worth the modest cost.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how high is the quality you're expecting, but you will certainly find GUI images on [Open Game Art](http://opengameart.org) that you can **legally** use.

Comment: This is not exactly what I meant, as I'm currently developing professional applications. This site is great, though, I think I'll come back to it at some point, so thanks!